# Java - Actionlistner in (not inner) runnable class doesn't perform

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, oop

I'm trying to make clean and OOP code for a java swing GUI.
So I made a class that implements Runnable and should handle all the actions.
All the data and components i stored in a data class full of getters and setters.

```
public class UserInterface{
...
    public void foo(){
        PanelActions panelActions = new PanelActions(); 
        Thread tProgressbar = new Thread(panelActions, "Update progressbar");
        tProgressbar.start();
    }
}

public class PanelActions implements Runnable{
    GUIdata data = new GUIdata();
    public void run(){

        //submitButton 
        data.getSubmitButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                  //Some code
            }           
        }); 

        //Browse Button
        data.getBrowseButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){      
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                  //Some code
            }           
        }); 
    };  
}
```

and the getter and setter class:

```
public class GUIdata{
    private JButton submitButton;
    private JButton browseButton;

    GUIdata(){
        submitButton = new JButton();
        browseButton = new JButton();
    }

    public JButton getSubmitButton() {
        return submitButton;
    }

    public void setSubmitButton(JButton submitButton) {
        this.submitButton = submitButton;
    }

    public JButton getBrowseButton() {
        return browseButton;
    }

    public void setBrowseButton(JButton browseButton) {
        this.browseButton = browseButton;
    }
}
```

But this way the code in the actionperformed isn't working. The thread starts and the run method is working great. But probably it doesn't like to add an `ActionListener` to a get methode. Even I tried this:

```
JButton browse = data.getBrowseButton();

browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        //Some code                 
    }
});
data.setBrowseButton(browse);seButton(browse);
```

But even that isn't the right way.

So does anybody know how to add an ActionListener to an Button from another class?
Thanks :)

Comment: These buttons don't seem to be registered in a UI anywhere.

Comment: I don't see any reason for not performing! But my question is: did you even tried to give it an action? did you try to punch it ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I add them in the UserInterface class, but that's  not intresting for this issue.

Comment: @Sage me neither, but it doesn't run the code in the actionPerformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute your button actions in separate thread DO NOT put creation of action listeners into method run, put actions you want to perform in method run.

1. Remove from PanelActions any runnable:

   ```
   public class PanelActions {
   GUIdata data = new GUIdata();


   //submitButton 
   data.getSubmitButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
             //Some code
       }           
   }); 

   //Browse Button
   data.getBrowseButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){      
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
             //Some code
       }           
   }); 
   }
   ```
2. In actionPerformed create a Runnable or Thread and start it execution

   ```
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
       Thread thread = new Thread() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               //Some code
           }
       };
       thread.start();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`"Update progressbar"` gives me the impression you might need `invokeLater`:

```
    data.getBrowseButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){      
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                //Some code
            });
        }           
    });
```

This lets the event handling thread handle the button click (actionPerformed). And only a bit later the code is executed and responsive, repainting the progressbar.

Another software design might be cleaner. You might use Action (extending AbstractAction). Have some actions and put them into JButtons.

Comment: Any event gets executed in the EDT. I didn't quite get your point. Inside `actionPerformed` function `Thread.currentThread()` will easily respond with: `Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]` stuff